# CustomValidator with onservervalidation returns false but control moving to next step asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I am using CustomValidator with onservervalidation. the server side function is firing properly and returns false value but the Validator is not displaying the error message but moving to the next step.

Code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator OnServerValidate="Naminee_Validate" 
 ErrorMessage="You cannot set yourself as Nominee"
 runat="server" Display="None">*</asp:CustomValidator>  

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary3" runat="server" DisplayMode="SingleParagraph"
  HeaderText="Error in saving the data: "  />

  protected void Naminee_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {           
         if (....)
            {
                e.IsValid = false;
            }
         else
            {
                e.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have other validator(s) in your markup code, other than 'CustomValidator' and you **do not use** client validation, set the *EnableClientScript* property (of those other validator(s)) to 'false'. The default of this property is 'true' even though it's not declared.

This solution solved a similar problem I add.

Comment: Can you see the asterisk when validation fires? What kind of indication you get when server side function fires? One more thing you could do is to set 'Display' property to Dynamic.

Comment: The function returns false but no * is displaying. control moves to next step of the process.

Comment: this control is inside the asp:Wizard control. this validation is working fine when clicking the button in the asp:Wizard header.

Comment: Can you join me in this chat room? [ASP.NET Validators](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10163/asp-net-validators)

Answer (score 1):

just added event handler shown below!

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/post/1385627.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the validation group property for your RequireFieldValidator, ValidationSummary and control on which you want to validate your code.

Answer (score -1):

use requiredfieldvalidator as your goal is to check it shud not be empty..

Comment: -1 The OP has not said that they want to check for *empty*, infact the error message suggests they really do need a `CustomValidator` not a `RequiredFieldValidator`